# Implementing android's default Gallery like view

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gallery

In Gallery app, first it shows all `Albums` in Thumbnail. On click of each `Albums` it shows all images in `GridView`. Then on click of `GridView` images it opens full screen.

**What I have done:**

Initially, I'm loading images(http images) in `GalleryView`(Horizontal scroll) and on Click of `GalleryView` items it opens images in `GridView`.Then on click of `GridView` items, it open in FullScreen. This is working :)

**What I'm looking for:**

1. In `Galleryview` I want to show only the albums.
2. On click of `GalleryView` items it has to open all images of that particular album in `GridView`.

I'm using Android Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Ok...so what problem going on?

Comment: In GalleryView, I want to show any one images of that particular album.

Comment: Ok...so after click on image of Gallery view you have to pass id of that image to new activity

Comment: ya i knw. I want to show All Albums(not images) in Gallery View. And On click of each albums it has to open all images of that particular album  in gridview.